# Generate Candidate 3 Itemsets in Python

Tags: python, set, apriori

I'm trying to generate candidate 3 itemsets in Python (without any packages besides Numpy and Pandas).
I have a list containing 82 sets, each with 2 items. This is called frequent_2_itemsets.
I have another set with 33 individual items. This is called item_set.

I'm trying to create a new list containing sets of 3 items. Each candidate 3-itemset in the new list:

- is a superset of at least one frequent 2-itemset
- every 3-itemset that has a frequent size-2 subset is already in the list
- and the new list does not contain duplicated sets

I started by trying to create a loop within a loop to add a third item to the frequent_2_itemsets:

```
for pair in frequent_2_itemsets:
    for i in item_set:
        pair.add(i)
```

but this is clearly not correct. Some help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don’t understand the second point of your bullet list

Comment: @TUI lover sorry, that part of the question wasn't worded well. It means that in the new list, every candidate 3-itemset must contain a subset from frequent_2_itemset

Comment: I see no difference with the first point then